# How to add a global exception handler/logger once in Mule

Tags: mule

We want to add a few lines of XML config to mule with an exception handler that logs to SLF4J instead of where they log right now (stdout). How do we add this?

We do NOT want to have to add this handler to every single flow (50+ flows, plus as people add flows, they may forget to add our exception handler).

Comment: Mule logging goes through Log4J not directly to STDOUT. Have you tried turning off the console appender?

Comment: hmmmm, thanks, let me rerun and retest this then...maybe my slf4j config is wrong(using logback with log4j adapter on top).

Comment: Your question remains valid though: "how to share a common exception handler across flows" is an interesting one :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of "how to share a common exception handler across flows" (in this case a catch-exception-strategy):

```
<catch-exception-strategy name="myGlobalCatchStrategy">
    <set-payload value="Hey something happened! : #[exception.getSummaryMessage()]" />
</catch-exception-strategy>

<configuration defaultExceptionStrategy-ref="myGlobalCatchStrategy" />

<flow name="global-catch-example">

    <inbound-endpoint address="vm://entry-point.in" exchange-pattern="request-response" />

    <test:component throwException="true" />

</flow>
```

Comment: no worries, we dropped mule after a productivity study showing POJO's were faster to develop than using mule as debugging xml instead of just debugging with a debugger was proven to be way slower.  We created some realistic examples that our project needed and it took 6 times longer with mule.

Comment: In the Mule Summits of fall '12, Mulesoft demonstrated the visual debugger of Mule Studio that will be available soon. It might change your mind in the future (or not).
Also most of the integration frameworks available hava Java or Scala DSL's that could make your debugging easier.